# How to lemmatize lists within lists

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

I am attempting this kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking.

The 'ingredients' column in this dataset consists of lists of the ingredients. I'm trying to lemmatize this column but after the running the code below it doesn't look like the ingredients column has changed at all.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')

traindf = pd.read_json('/Users//Documents/kaggle/whats- 
cooking/train.json')
testdf = pd.read_json('/Users//Documents/kaggle/whats- 
cooking/test.json')
traindf.head()

traindf['ingredients']=traindf['ingredients'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
testdf['ingredients']=testdf['ingredients'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))

for recipe in traindf['ingredients']: recipe = word_tokenize(recipe)
for recipe in testdf['ingredients']: recipe = word_tokenize(recipe)

for recipe in traindf['ingredients']:
   for ingredient in recipe:
        WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(recipe)
```

Comment: Are you sure you assign the value to something?

Comment: @TheFool I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: btw, in the second `apply` statement, `testdf['ingredients']=traindf['ingredients'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))`, the right side of `=` should be `testdf`, not `traindf`. Also, the first two `for recipe in` loops don't accomplish anything.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that. Why don't the loops work - are they unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the mistake I made was that I called the lemmatizer on 'recipe' instead of 'ingredient' in the last line.